# Java EKE, ObjectInputStream wrong readObject()

Tags: java, client-server, basic-authentication, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I try to realize a EKE with AES-256 for a university project.
The main problem is that when the client call `writeObject()` to the server, the last one receive a wrong object with different ciphertext to decrypt and different initialization vector.

This is the Client Alice:

```js
package Secondo;
import java.math.BigInteger;


import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;

import java.security.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.*;

import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
/**
 * 
 * @author Bazzotti 
 * 
 * Alice.
 * 
 * rappresenta il client che si vuole autenticare al Server
 *
 */


public class Alice 
{
    
    public static final int JabberServerPORT = 9999;
    //public static final byte[] JabberServerADDRESS = new byte[]{127,0,0,1};
    
    public  static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        
        
        
        
        // p è un numero primo in modo che qualsiasi g possa generare un insieme abbastanza grande
        // inoltre perchè Diffie-Hellman sia sicuro anche ((p-1)/2) deve essere primo
        
        int bitLength = 512; 
        SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
        
        //Attributi per DH
        BigInteger p;
        BigInteger g = new BigInteger(bitLength, rnd);
           
        
        BigInteger Sa=new BigInteger(bitLength, rnd);
        do{
            
            p = g.max(Sa).nextProbablePrime();
         
        } while (p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).shiftRight(1).isProbablePrime(50));
        
        
        
        BigInteger Ta=g.modPow(Sa,p);
        
        
        
        //
        String Alice=MyUtil.leggiString("inserisci il nome");
        String password=MyUtil.leggiString("inserisci la password");
        
      // System.out.println("stringa del BigInteger Ta "+Ta.toString());
        System.out.println("lunghezza bit Ta"+Ta.bitCount()+"lunghezza bit p"+p.bitCount());
        DatiChipertext prima_cifratura= cifraturaAES( chiaveAES(password),Ta.toByteArray());
        
        byte[] A=prima_cifratura.getChipertext();
        byte[] iv=prima_cifratura.getIv();
        Socket socket=null;
        
        
       
       System.out.println(Alice+","+A+","+g+p+","+iv);
       
        
           
        
        try {
            
            
            socket = new Socket("localhost", JabberServerPORT);
            
            
            
           
                
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("mi sto connettendo al server");
        
        
        
        
       // System.out.println("lunghezza primo messaggio "+primo_messaggio.length());
         // Invio di A Alice g p
       // System.out.println("lunghezza A"+A.length());
       // System.out.println("chiave primo messaggio"+password);
        PrimoMessaggioAlice primo_messaggio= new PrimoMessaggioAlice(Alice,A,g,p,iv);
        out.writeObject(primo_messaggio);
        out.reset();
        
        System.out.println("primo messaggio inviato");
         // Ricezione di Bob e B
         
        PrimoMessaggioBob primo_messaggio_ricevuto = (PrimoMessaggioBob)in.readObject();
        
               
        
        System.out.println("primo messaggio ricevuto");
      
        
       //  Decifro ottenendo Tb e c1
         
       
        String Bob=primo_messaggio_ricevuto.getBob();
        byte[] iv2=primo_messaggio_ricevuto.getIv();
        byte[] B=primo_messaggio_ricevuto.getB();
       
        
        System.out.println("B ricevuto "+B+" iv "+iv2);
        /**Cipher mDecipher = Cipher.getInstance ("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        mDecipher.init (Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, chiaveAES(password));
        */
       
        byte[] B_decriptato=decifraturaAES(chiaveAES(password),B,iv2);
       
        byte[] c1= new byte [4];
        byte[] Tb_decriptato= new byte[B_decriptato.length-4];
        for(int i=0;i<B_decriptato.length;i++)
        {
            if(i<(B_decriptato.length-4))
                Tb_decriptato[i]=B_decriptato[i];
            else
                c1[i]=B_decriptato[i];
        }
      
      //Sostituito con Tb dato da bob
        BigInteger Tb=new BigInteger(Tb_decriptato);
        
        //
        
        //Chiave per i metodi successivi
        BigInteger Kt=Tb.modPow(Sa,p);
        
        
        
        byte[] c2=(SecureRandom.getSeed(4));
        
      //creazione della chiave effimera
        
       
        byte[] secondo_messaggio=concat(c1,c2);
        SecretKeySpec ephimeral_key= new SecretKeySpec(Kt.toByteArray(),"AES");
        
        
     //   System.out.println("lunghezza Kt "+Kt.bitLength()+"lunghezza p "+p.bitLength());
        
        
        
        DatiChipertext secondo_messaggio_chipertext=cifraturaAES(ephimeral_key,secondo_messaggio);
        byte[] secondo_messaggio_criptato=secondo_messaggio_chipertext.getChipertext();
        byte[] iv3=secondo_messaggio_chipertext.getIv();
        System.out.println(iv3);
    //   System.out.println("secondo messaggio inviato "+secondo_messaggio_criptato.getBytes()+"ephimeral key "+Kt.toByteArray());
        /**System.out.println("Tb "+Tb.toString()+" Ta "+Ta.toString());
        */
        
        SecondoMessaggioA secondo_messaggio_da_inviare=new SecondoMessaggioA(secondo_messaggio_criptato,iv3);
        /**
         * Invio del secondo messaggi ocriptato
         */
        
         System.out.println("secondo messaggio inviato "+secondo_messaggio_da_inviare.getC1C2()+secondo_messaggio_da_inviare.getIv());
         
        
        out.writeObject(secondo_messaggio_da_inviare);
        
        out.flush();
        /**
         * Ricezione di c2'
         */
        
        System.out.println("secondo messaggio inviato ");
        
        SecondoMessaggioBob secondo_messaggio_ricevuto= (SecondoMessaggioBob)in.readObject();
       
        System.out.println("secondo messaggio ricevuto ");
        System.out.println(secondo_messaggio_ricevuto);
        /**
         * Verifica che c2 sia uguale a c2'
         */
        
       /* Cipher mDecipher2 = Cipher.getInstance ("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        mDecipher2.init (Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, chiaveAES(Kt.toByteArray().toString()));
        */
        
       
        
        byte[] iv4=secondo_messaggio_ricevuto.getIv();
        
        byte[] c2_cifrato=secondo_messaggio_ricevuto.getC2();
        byte[] c2_ricevuto=decifraturaAES(ephimeral_key,c2_cifrato,iv4);
        
        if(c2_ricevuto.equals(c2))
            System.out.println("Server Autenticato");
        else
            System.out.println("Server NON Autenticato");
            
            
      }finally {
            System.out.println("********** Chiudo il socket...");
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("********** Eccezione b" + e);
            }
        }
     
        
        
    }
    
    
    private static DatiChipertext cifraturaAES  (SecretKey secret, byte[] messaggio) throws Exception
    {
        
        
        //cifratura
             
        Cipher mEcipher = Cipher.getInstance ("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
       /* byte[] iv = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
         IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        mEcipher.init (Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret,ivspec);
        */
        
        mEcipher.init (Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
        AlgorithmParameters params = mEcipher.getParameters();

        byte []iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
        System.out.println("iv usato "+iv);
       // byte[] messaggio_da_codificare = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(messaggio);
       
        //chipertext è ok lungo 80 byte
        
        //String stringa_cifrata=new String (chiphertext);
        
        //Devono essere 80 caratteri o un multiplo
        //System.out.println("lunghezza caratteri stringa messaggio"+stringa_cifrata.length());
        
        
        return new DatiChipertext (messaggio,iv);
        
        
    }
     
    private static SecretKey chiaveAES (String chiave) throws Exception
    {
        //creazione della chiave
        //SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
       // byte [] salt={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
       // SecretKeySpec tmp = new SecretKeySpec (chiave.getBytes("UTF-8"),"AES");
      //  SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret (spec);
        
        //calcolo sha-256 della chiave
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] hash = digest.digest(chiave.getBytes());
       
        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec (hash, "AES");
        return secret;
    }
    
    private static byte[] decifraturaAES (SecretKey chiave, byte[] messaggio, byte[] iv) throws Exception
    {
        
        
        
        
         Cipher mDecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        
         IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
           mDecipher.init (Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, chiave,ivspec);
        
           // byte [] messaggio_da_decodificare=DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(messaggio);
          
           // System.out.println("lunghezza byte chiper"+messaggio_da_decodificare.length);
            //byte [] messaggio_da_decodificare=messaggio.getBytes("UTF-8");
            return mDecipher.doFinal(messaggio);
            
    }
    
    public static byte[] concat(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
           int aLen = a.length;
           int bLen = b.length;
           byte[] c= new byte[aLen+bLen];
           System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, aLen);
           System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, aLen, bLen);
           return c;
        }
}
```

And this is the Server Bob:

```js
package Secondo;


import java.math.BigInteger;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;


import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;






import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;









import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.math.BigInteger;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;

import java.security.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.*;

import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;


/**
 * 
 * @author Bazzotti 
 * 
 * Bob.
 * 
 * rappresenta il Server che deve autenticare il Client
 *
 */


public class Bob 
{
    
    private static String Bob ="Bob";
    public static final int JABBERSERVERPORT = 9999;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        
        Utenti utenti=new Utenti();
        
        utenti.inizzializzazioneUtenti();
        
        
        ServerSocket ServS = new ServerSocket(JABBERSERVERPORT);
        Socket socket = null;
                    
        int bitLength = 256; 
        SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
        
        try {
            
            socket = ServS.accept();
            
            
            
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
         
            out.flush();
            
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            /**
             * Ricezione della stringa
             */
            
            System.out.println("sto aspettando la connessione");
            
           PrimoMessaggioAlice primo_messaggio_ricevuto=(PrimoMessaggioAlice)in.readObject() ;
           

           
           
           
            
          //  System.out.println(Alice_A_g_p.length);
            String Alice =primo_messaggio_ricevuto.getAlice();
            
            
            String password =utenti.cerca(Alice);
            
            byte[] iv1=primo_messaggio_ricevuto.getIv();
            
            BigInteger p= primo_messaggio_ricevuto.getP();
            BigInteger g= primo_messaggio_ricevuto.getG();
            
            byte[] A=primo_messaggio_ricevuto.getA();
        //creazione della chiave
            
            SecretKey chiave=chiaveAES (password);
            
           
            System.out.println(" A è "+A+" iv byte "+iv1);
           
        //Decodifica di A
            
            
           // System.out.println("chiave primo messaggio"+password);
            BigInteger Ta=new BigInteger(decifraturaAES(chiave,A,iv1));
            
            
            
        //    byte [] salt =Alice_A_g_p_salt[4].getBytes("UTF-8");
        //Calcolo Tb
            
            byte[] c1=(SecureRandom.getSeed(4));
            
            BigInteger Sb=new BigInteger(bitLength-1, rnd);
            
            BigInteger Tb=g.modPow(Sb,p);
        //Crittografo messaggio
            
            byte[] primo_messaggio_da_crittografare=concat(Tb.toByteArray(),c1);
            
    //      System.out.println("Tb, c1"+primo_messaggio_da_crittografare.getBytes());
           
            
            DatiChipertext primo_chipertext=cifraturaAES(chiaveAES(password),primo_messaggio_da_crittografare);
            byte[] B=primo_chipertext.getChipertext();
            byte[] iv2=primo_chipertext.getIv();
            
            PrimoMessaggioBob Bob_B= new PrimoMessaggioBob(Bob,B,iv2);
            
        //    System.out.println(" B "+B.getBytes());
            //System.out.println("Bob, B byte "+primo_messaggio_inviato);
        //    System.out.println("Bob, B stringa "+Bob_B.getBytes()+"\n iv "+iv);
            
            
            //Chiave per i metodi successivi
            BigInteger Kt=Ta.modPow(Sb,p);
            
            /**
             * Invio di Tb e Bob
             */
            out.writeObject(Bob_B);
            
            out.flush();
            
            System.out.println("primo messaggio inviato");
            /**
             * Ricevo secondo messaggio c1 e c2
             */
            
            SecondoMessaggioA secondo_messaggio_ricevuto=(SecondoMessaggioA)in.readObject();
            
            
            System.out.println("secondo messaggio ricevuto");
           
            
        //Decodifico c1 e c2
            
            
            
            /**
             * Trasformazione in stringa non corretta, oppure dimensione non va bene
             */
            System.out.println("lunghezza Kt "+Kt.bitLength()+"lunghezza p "+p.bitLength());
            SecretKeySpec ephimeral_key= new SecretKeySpec(Kt.toByteArray(),"AES");
                  
            
            
            // System.out.println("secondo messaggio ricevuto "+secondo_messaggio_ricevuto_stringa.getBytes()+"ephimeral key "+Kt.toByteArray());
           //  System.out.println("Tb "+Tb.toString()+" Ta "+Ta.toString());
             
            
             
             byte[] iv3=secondo_messaggio_ricevuto.getIv();
             
             System.out.println(iv3);
             
             byte[] secondo_messaggio_da_decodificare=secondo_messaggio_ricevuto.getC1C2();
             byte[] c1_c2=decifraturaAES(ephimeral_key,secondo_messaggio_da_decodificare,iv3);
             
             byte[] c1_ricevuto=new byte[4];
             byte[] c2=new byte[4];
             
             for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
             {
                 c1_ricevuto[i]=c1_c2[i];
             }
             for (int i=4;i<9;i++)
             {
                 c2[i]=c1_c2[i];
             }
             
            
             if(c1_ricevuto.equals(c1))
             {
                 System.out.println("Autenticato il client");
                 
                 
                 DatiChipertext secondo_messaggio_criptato=cifraturaAES(ephimeral_key,c2);
                 
                 byte[] c2_criptato=secondo_messaggio_criptato.getChipertext();
                 byte[] iv4=secondo_messaggio_criptato.getIv();
                
                 SecondoMessaggioBob secondo_messaggio_da_inviare=new SecondoMessaggioBob(c2_criptato,iv4);
                 /**
                  * invio di c2
                  */
                 
                 
                 out.writeObject(secondo_messaggio_da_inviare);
                 out.flush();
             }
                
             else
                 System.out.println("client sbagliato");
             
        
            }finally {
                System.out.println("********** Chiudo il socket...");
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("********** Eccezione b" + e);
                }
        
        ServS.close();
    }

    }
    private static DatiChipertext cifraturaAES  (SecretKey secret, byte[] messaggio) throws Exception
    {
        
        
        //cifratura
             
        Cipher mEcipher = Cipher.getInstance ("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
       /* byte[] iv = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
         IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        mEcipher.init (Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret,ivspec);
        */
        
        mEcipher.init (Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
        AlgorithmParameters params = mEcipher.getParameters();

        byte []iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
        System.out.println("iv usato "+iv);
       // byte[] messaggio_da_codificare = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(messaggio);
       
        //chipertext è ok lungo 80 byte
        
        //String stringa_cifrata=new String (chiphertext);
        
        //Devono essere 80 caratteri o un multiplo
        //System.out.println("lunghezza caratteri stringa messaggio"+stringa_cifrata.length());
        
        
        return new DatiChipertext (messaggio,iv);
        
        
    }
     
    private static SecretKey chiaveAES (String chiave) throws Exception
    {
        //creazione della chiave
        //SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
       // byte [] salt={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
       // SecretKeySpec tmp = new SecretKeySpec (chiave.getBytes("UTF-8"),"AES");
      //  SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret (spec);
        
        //calcolo sha-256 della chiave
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] hash = digest.digest(chiave.getBytes());
       
        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec (hash, "AES");
        return secret;
    }
    
    private static byte[] decifraturaAES (SecretKey chiave, byte[] messaggio, byte[] iv) throws Exception
    {
        
        
        
        
         Cipher mDecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        
         IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
           mDecipher.init (Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, chiave,ivspec);
        
           // byte [] messaggio_da_decodificare=DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(messaggio);
          
           // System.out.println("lunghezza byte chiper"+messaggio_da_decodificare.length);
            //byte [] messaggio_da_decodificare=messaggio.getBytes("UTF-8");
            return mDecipher.doFinal(messaggio);
            
    }
    
    public static byte[] concat(byte[] a, byte[] b)
    {
           int aLen = a.length;
           int bLen = b.length;
           byte[] c= new byte[aLen+bLen];
           System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, aLen);
           System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, aLen, bLen);
           return c;
        }
}
```

And the Object that i passed is PrimoMessaggioAlice (FirstMessageFromAlice)

```js
package Secondo;
import java.math.*;
import java.io.*;
public class PrimoMessaggioAlice implements Serializable {
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String Alice;
    private byte[] A;
    private BigInteger g;
    private BigInteger p;
    private byte [] iv;
    
public PrimoMessaggioAlice(String _Alice, byte[] _A, BigInteger _g, BigInteger _p, byte[] _iv)
{
    Alice=_Alice;
    A=_A;
    g=_g;
    p=_p;
    iv=_iv;
}


public String getAlice()
{
    return Alice;
    
}

public byte[] getA()
{
    return A;
}

public byte[] getIv()
{
    return iv;
}
public BigInteger getP()
{
    return p;
}

public BigInteger getG()
{
    return g;
}


}
```

That is the same in the Client and in the server.

whent Alice send PrimoMessaggioAlice with (A=[B@6e56ae and  iv=[B@1b3967)
Bob read usually PrimoMessaggioAlice with (A=[B@19e8f17 and iv=[B@c44b88)

Thank for the Help

Comment: These are just the results of calling `byte[].toString()`. They aren't the contents.

Comment: yes, I used this print only to see if they are the same to the Client and to the server. Because Eclipse return  javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. And I was thinking that this is the problem.